# Sending headers in a custom policy to call a restful provider in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

As part of a custom policy, we make a call to a Rest service. We need to send HTTP headers as part of this. Is it possible to send HTTP Headers as part of a `RestfulProvider` call?

We would at least like to send `Accept=application/json` to the service.

```xml
 <TechnicalProfile Id="Restful-ProxyAuthValidation">
  <DisplayName>Restful Claims Provider</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://contoso.azurewebsites.net/api/GFAuth</Item>
    <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
    <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
    <Item Key="issuer">https://contoso.azurewebsites.net/</Item>
  </Metadata>
  ....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send the claims in headers by adding the following metadata item to the (RestfulProvider) technical profile:

```
<Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Header</Item>
```

All the `InputClaims` of the technical profile will be sent in headers.

Comment: Not trying to send Claims in header. I would like to send Claims in body as defined in the example, but would also like to include standard headers such as Accept and Content-Type

Comment: @mdgdk "We need to send HTTP headers" is a direct quote from your question.  Perhaps you can revisit your question?

Comment: No, I still want to send the claims in the body as content, but I need to add some fixed and variable headers in the REST call - like Content-Type and access key.

Comment: That is not currently possible, but it is in our backlog.

Comment: `That is not currently possible, but it is in our backlog` - Three years later it seems still not possible. Agile much?

Comment: I'm sorry to ask but do we have update on this @OmerIqbal? I'd like to set headers Accept and Content-Type with application/vnd.api+json